# How to set up a simple, friendly skinned, public access computer

Tags: software-recommendation, internet, skype, kiosk, cybercafe

I could do with advice about software options available to me for a requirement that has dropped in my lap.

Our church has a linked coffee shop which is open to the public and is frequently visited by people from disadvantaged backgrounds. These people would really benefit from having internet access, word processing, Links to local services (doctors, crisis help centre, etc..) on a public access appliance. We would like to create and run a pilot to see if we can provide just that using Linux on a touch screen all-in-one (we have been given several ASUS 2GB eeePCs).

The Requirement will be for registered user or guest log-in leading to a simple environment skinned to offer big friendly buttons for the major services (Skype, Internet, "show me how to..." videos, call a doctor, find a job etc...)

I am aware there are several internet cafe systems out there, but they seem to be all to do with billing and we'd be more interested in the rapid development of the skinned environment. Does anyone have experience in this and could point me to any useful development software, project or environment?

Comment: I'm looking at Linutop, which runs well on the hardware and is quite nice but I really am still looking for a simple way to have Big friendly buttons for 'digitally challenged' users.

Comment: Hi I read this question some time ago but I'm sorry I didn't find anything helpfull for you. Maybe a webinterface could do the trick?

If you find something it would be nice if you share it anyway because it is an interesting question. Maybe just the Askubuntu page was the wrong space for it?